# Function for language C that replicates the results of eig in MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I want to find the function of calculating eigenvalue and eigenvectors in language C which has same results as MATLAB's `eig` function.

I'm currently using GNU Scientific Library eigenvalue solver. However, it can't get same eigenvectors as the results of MATLAB `eig` function when the eigenvalues are overlapped.

How can I replicate MATLAB's results in C?

Comment: If you have some code that does not work as expected - you should post it in a form of [mcve] and state the expectations vs the actual behavior.

Comment: When there are multiple equal eigenvalues, the corresponding eigenvectors form a subspace. Any set of orthogonal unit vectors in this subspace are valid eigenvectors. There is no way to get the exact same ones as in MATLAB unless you run the exact same code, but MATLAB is closed-source, so you can't copy their code. I don't think there's a solution, you will have to do with equivalent but non-identical results.

Comment: Matlab uses either the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) algorithm or the [generalized Schur decomposition algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition): you'll have to implement one of those in order to try and get close to what's done in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab uses either the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) algorithm or the [generalized Schur decomposition algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition): you'll have to implement one of those in order to try and get close to what's done in Matlab.

An example of how the first method could be implemented in C can be found [here](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Emcpeek/software/CCQLSpackage1.3/cholesky.c).